# How do I delete all these menus?

Tags: interface

How do I delete all these menus? I can't see my model.

[image]

Comment: on the top right of each window you have a small triangle that you can catch, them move it in the direction of the window you want to crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the drop down menu here. And click on Default.

[image]